# How to transform HTML encoded XML?

Tags: character-encoding, xml-serialization, xslt-2.0

I have an input XML like

```
<values xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;Test objectgroupNr="001"/&gt;&lt;bezeichnung&gt;A&amp;amp;B &lt;/bezeichnung&gt;</values>
```

which has HTML encoded characters that I want to transform to "plain" XML encoding:

```
<values xsi:type="xsd:string">
        <Test objectgroupNr="001"/>
        <bezeichnung>A&amp;B</bezeichnung>
</values>
```

I could change some characters with

```
<xsl:character-map name="fischer">
            <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
            <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>
</xsl:character-map>      
<xsl:output method="xml" use-character-maps="fischer"/>
```

But it does not seem to be a good idea to type in all possible special characters like Ä, Ü, ß, é and so on...

Can this be done in an easy way with XSLT? The transformation takes place in the environment of Sonic ESB using Saxon 8.9.

Comment: Which version of which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? With the commercial versions of Saxon 9 there is an extension function to parse a string as XML so you could use that.

Comment: See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/parse.xml. With XSLT 3.0 also implemented in the latest Saxon version you could use http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/parse-xml.xml.

Comment: And XPath 3.0 also has http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment which is more suited to your data but I am not sure Saxon supports that one already. But you can of course wrap the contents of your `values` element in a root element and then parse with `parse-xml` and simply take the child nodes of the root wrapper.

Comment: Using Saxon 8.9 and edited question accordingly. That leaves me without XSLT/XPath 3.0 I fear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.saxonica.com/documentation8.9/extensions/functions/parse.html the extension function is supported so you should be able to use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="values">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(concat('&lt;root&gt;', ., '&lt;/root&gt;'))/*/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

where you put `xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"` as a namespace declaration into the stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you - that does the job. I just had to combine it with an identity transform because it otherwise removes the tag that is matched.